# Send operation timed out when producing events to Azure eventhubs

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

I have a long-running application that uses azure eventhub SDK (5.1.0), continually publishing data to Azure event hub. The service threw the below exception after few days. What could be the cause of this and how we can overcome this?

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "SendTimeout-timer" reactor.core.Exceptions$BubblingException: com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: Entity(abc): Send operation timed out, errorContext[NAMESPACE: abc-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net, PATH: abc-metrics, REFERENCE_ID: 70288acf171a4614ab6dcfe2884ee9ec_G2S2, LINK_CREDIT: 210]
at reactor.core.Exceptions.bubble(Exceptions.java:173)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onErrorDropped(Operators.java:612)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onError(FluxTimeout.java:203)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:185)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:251)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxHide.java:132)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:185)
at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorSender$SendTimeout.run(ReactorSender.java:565)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: Entity(abc-metrics): Send operation timed out, errorContext[NAMESPACE: abc-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net, PATH: abc-metrics, REFERENCE_ID: 70288acf171a4614ab6dcfe2884ee9ec_G2S2, LINK_CREDIT: 210]
at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorSender$SendTimeout.run(ReactorSender.java:562)
... 2 more
```

I'm using `Azure eventhub` `Java SDK 5.1.0`

Comment: Does the application stop working after the exception occurs? Or does it fail for that single send operation?
The "SendTimeout-Timer" is used to wait for an ACK from the service to say that the message was successfully sent.

Comment: @Connie Yau
The application stopped working after the exception

Answer (score 0):

According to official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-messaging-exceptions#timeoutexception):

> A TimeoutException indicates that a user-initiated operation is taking
> longer than the operation timeout.
>
> For Event Hubs, the timeout is specified either as part of the
> connection string, or through ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder. The
> error message itself might vary, but it always contains the timeout
> value specified for the current operation.
>
> **Common causes**
>
> There are two common causes for this error: incorrect
> configuration, or a transient service error.
>
> - **Incorrect configuration** The operation timeout might be too small for
>   the operational condition. The default value for the operation timeout
>   in the client SDK is 60 seconds. Check to see if your code has the
>   value set to something too small. The condition of the network and CPU
>   usage can affect the time it takes for a particular operation to
>   complete, so the operation timeout should not be set to a small value.
> - **Transient service error** Sometimes the Event Hubs service can
>   experience delays in processing requests; for example, during periods
>   of high traffic. In such cases, you can retry your operation after a
>   delay, until the operation is successful. If the same operation still
>   fails after multiple attempts, visit the Azure service status site to
>   see if there are any known service outages.

If you are consistently seeing this error frequently, I would suggest to reach Azure support for a deeper look.

Comment: I also referred to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-messaging-exceptions#timeoutexception). That does not contain a clue to this issue :/.
However I'm not consistently seeing this error.